# Is the image of a cyclic group $G$ a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is the image of a cyclic group under a homomorphism $\phi : G → G'$ always
>   a normal subgroup of $G'$?

I believe the answer is yes as $G$ is abelian (since it is isomorphic to $Z$ or $Z_n$). So $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b) = \phi(ba) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$. Thus the image is also abelian. However, I am not sure if this proves it is normal as $G'$ is not necessarily abelian. Still, we pick $j \in \phi(G)$ and $g \in G'$. We want to show that $g^{-1}jg \in \phi(G)$. I am stuck on this step as I feel like I am missing some key property to make it all work. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: In effect, this is asking whether every cyclic subgroup of a group $H$ is normal. Is this the case for standard examples of non-Abelian groups, like say symmetric or dihedral groups?

Comment: You're correct that abelian groups always take normal subgroups. The way you wrote your equalities doesn't really follow, but it's still correct. As Lord Shark already commented, check the subgroups of the Dihedral group to figure out whether this holds generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an injective homomorphism $Z_2\to S_3$ whose image is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$.

To be concrete, map the identity element of $Z_2$ to the identity permutation $(1)(2)(3)$ and map the nonidentity element of $Z_2$ to the permutation $(12)(3)$. The image is $\{(1)(2)(3),(12)(3)\}$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$.

All that you can say about the image of a cyclic group $G$ under a homomorphism $G\to G^\prime$ is that the image is cyclic subgroup of $G^\prime$. However, cyclic subgroups are not necessarily normal. The first counterexample is the one I gave above where $S_3$ has a non-normal cyclic subgroup of order $2$ (in fact, there are $3$ such subgroups).

Comment: What would the image of the example you gave look like?

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi : G → G'$ is Homomorphism from a cyclic group $G$ to some other group $G'$ then notice that, as $G$ is cyclic $$\exists a \in G$$ such that $G=<a>$ so for any $b \in G, b=a^r$ for some $r<n$ where $n$ is order of $G$, and $$\phi (b) = \phi (a^r) = {(\phi (a))}^r$$ as $\phi$ is homomorphism, notice that $b$ is generalized element of $G$ so we can do this for any element of $G$ , in fact we can say that homomorphic image of cyclic group $G$ is cyclic. Thus $\phi (G)$ is cyclic subgroup of $G'$ that is $\phi (G) = <\phi (a)>$

Now for $g,g^{-1} \in G'$ and for some $\phi (k) \in \phi (G)$ $$g\circ \phi (k)\circ g^{-1} = g\circ {(\phi (a))}^s \circ g^{-1} = {(g\circ \phi (a) \circ g^{-1})}^s$$ for some $s<m$ where $m$ is order of $\phi (G)$

And so $\phi (G)$ is normal in $G'$ iff $g\phi (a)g^{-1} \in \phi (G) \ \forall g\in G'$ !

So what you are saying is **not always true!**